# How to debug "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am newbie trying to learn Hibernate. I am trying to set up eclipse with the example hibernate program online and check if its working properly but I get this error.

Console Error

```
    Jul 17, 2018 12:29:27 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:27 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:27 PM org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService <init>
INFO: HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:28 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:28 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jul 17, 2018 12:29:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 12 more
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 5.3//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-5.3.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">Naveen</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>  
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My property xml for the postgres table employee.hbm.xml

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 5.3//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-5.3.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="com.javatpoint.mypackage.Employee" table="emp1000">  
    <id name="id">  
     <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <property name="firstName"></property>  
    <property name="lastName"></property>  

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee class getter and setter

```
    package com.javatpoint.mypackage;  





public class Employee {  
private int id;  
private String firstName,lastName;  

public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
public String getFirstName() {  
    return firstName;  
}  
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {  
    this.firstName = firstName;  
}  
public String getLastName() {  
    return lastName;  
}  
public void setLastName(String lastName) {  
    this.lastName = lastName;  
}  
}
```

My main method where transaction is written.

```
    package com.javatpoint.mypackage;  

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;  

public class StoreData {  

    public static void main( String[] args )  
    {  
         StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();  
            Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();  

        SessionFactory factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();  
        Session session = factory.openSession();  
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();  

         Employee e1=new Employee();    
            e1.setId(1);    
            e1.setFirstName("Gaurav");    
            e1.setLastName("Chawla");    

       session.save(e1);  
       t.commit();  
       System.out.println("successfully saved");    
        factory.close();  
        session.close();     
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out I used postgres dialect and driver.

```
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
```